# How can I embed Perl Interpreter inside a C++ application making DLL?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, perl, windows-7

I need a DLL built in C++ having Perl interpreter inside it and a Perl library [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) by Phil Harvey being called by C++ functions.

I want to do it on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010 VC++ installed. Which Perl distribution is best for this task: [Strawberry](http://strawberryperl.com/) or [ActiveState Perl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl)? Also, which Perl compilation command: nmake or dmake?

In the end the final deliverable should be a DLL. This can be imported into any program C etc and the DLL functions will be called which will internally be calling Phil Harvey's [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) library functions/arguments/switches.

Comment: Why is `system("perl.exe foo.pl")` not acceptable?

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49168/how-can-i-embed-perl-inside-a-c-application seems to be alike, but the answers were not for Visual Studio / Windows.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got Perl installed, the first thing you should do is look at the manpage for perlembed, i.e. "man perlembed" on Unix systems. Since you are on Windows, you are better off looking at the official [Perl documentation on the web for "perlembed"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html).

There's a specific section on Win32 on that information page. As for the specifics and caveats of including perl as a DLL, I'm not much help there.

Comment: MOSHBEAR; Thanks for every one reply. I can not use .EXE as .EXE can be embedded in a DLL. The final deliverable should be only .DLL

Comment: .EXE if included in VC++ project and .DLL is made but the final deliverable will be two files........EXE and .DLL placed in same folder. which is not wanted......Only .DLL....thats why embedding perl interpreter and executing exiftool philharvey source code to call its perl functions through VC++ and subsequently make the DLL

Comment: sorry.....EXE file can never be embedded in a .DLL .....or .EXE is binary can't be read......

Answer (score 0):

It could be a little overkill, but [a SWIG page](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html) mentions accessing Perl from NMAKE, and by extension, Visual Studio.