# Perl to C to DLL

Tags: c, perl, object, dll

I'm looking for a way to take a Perl script and turn it into a DLL. I know C can be compiled to object code and then to a DLL. Since Perl is C-based, can it be compiled to C and then to a object code, then a DLL?

I'm not worried about speed loss. I know from Perl to C there won't be a speed gain. My main concern is simply having a WIN32 DLL or a .NET DLL that I can package up and send out to use cross-business.

Comment: "Since PERL is C-based" - What do you mean by this?  "I know from PERL to C there won't be a speed gain" - You know this how?  "a WIN32 DLL or a .NET DLL" - The differences between these are not insignificant.  You seem to be tinkering around with terminology and technologies you don't fully understand.  What is it you're really trying to accomplish?

Comment: FWIW, the question and the intended goal (which is explicitly stated near the end) are perfectly clear to me.

Comment: @daxim: I understand that he's trying to compile PERL code into a DLL.  That's clear enough.  But _why_?  It sounds like he's starting down a road and wants help continuing down that already-chosen road when he really should have taken a different road in the first place.

Comment: PERL is easily integrated with with C, and I believe the interpreter is written in C. I know there won't be a speed gain, because in translating from PERL to C, the interpreter functionality is essentially translated over to create a C version of PERL, making the speed the same. What I want was fully outlined above. I need a DLL when starting with a PERL script. The DLL will be used on a Windows 32-bit machine. I am fairly certina a .NET DLL would work as well, but WIN32 DLL would be best. I do understand the terminologies well enough to formulate a question, which is the purpose of this forum

Comment: FYI, the name of the language is Perl and the name of the interpreter is `perl`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199457/how-can-i-embed-perl-interpreter-inside-a-c-application-making-dll and the linked question in the comments.

Comment: @ikegami: please undelete your answer - it *is* relevant as it details how you'd go about creating such a solution from scratch (ie by embedding the perl interpreter and writing a small wrapper which does initialization and script execution); it's *probably* possible to make it work with the Strawberry Perl DLL without having to compile a custom version...

Comment: @Christoph: Are you referring to this link: http://search.cpan.org/~flora/perl-5.14.2/pod/perlembed.pod posted in a previously deleted answer? I've been looking through it and it seems very helpful. I just didn't catch the poster before it got deleted.

Comment: @steventnorris: that's the one, redirected via http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlembed

Comment: @ikegami: Definitely repost. This looks very relevant, and I think it may work for my end-goal.

Comment: Using perlcc (http://search.cpan.org/dist/B-C/script/perlcc.PL), you can translate perl to a c program. Then you can use gcc or a comparable compiler to compile to object code and then to a dll. Does anyone see any problem with this?

Comment: Except that it is to be considered VERY experimental?

Comment: Perlcc is very experimental? I haven't used it in the past so I'm not certain or it's performance. What are the known drawbacks?

Answer (score 4):

[ActiveState Perl Dev Kit](http://www.activestate.com/perl-dev-kit) supports compiling to .NET assemblies and ActiveX controls (which is a kind of DLL). Earlier versions of ActiveState Perl shipped with [PerlEz](http://www.xav.com/perl/site/lib/Pod/PerlEz.html) for embedding Perl functions into a host DLL.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no ActiveState PERL Dev Kit. It's an unobtainable application in my situation due to business cost. I'll check into it as a possibility though, if I can get it passed up the ladder. Does it handle Win32 DLLs as well or just .NET and ActiveX controls?

Comment: I don't know; for the specifics you should read the whitepaper and contact their sales department.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the answer. I'll dig into that and see if it meets needs.

Comment: Your business can't afford a $300 license for PDK?

Comment: Business expenditure needs approval. Approval requires necessity. Until other options are exhausted, there is no necessity.